# Why does the condition "3 > 5 in range(10)" return False in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unable to understand the logic behind python returning `False` for the following condition:

```
3 > 5 in range(10)
```

while returning `True` for:

```
False in range(10)
```

Comment: Because it's evaluated as `3 > 5 and 5 in range(10)`, per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons, and 3 is smaller than 5. Try `(3 > 5) in range(10)`, instead.

Comment: Why would anyone write `3 > 5 in range(10)` though? and what would they mean by it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the comment by @jonrsharpe is the right answer, it wasn't trivial to me, and maybe also to you, so I'll break it down:

The expression is evaluated like this:

1. `3 > 5 in range(10)`
2. `3 > 5 and 5 in range(10)`
3. `False and 5 in range(10) == False` (`False and ...` [short circuits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) to `False`)

The reason for `1 -> 2` is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). To sum it up, it's like `x < y < z` means `x < y` **and** `y < z`.

Trying something like `(3 > 5) in range(10)` would be evaluated like this:

1. `(3 > 5) in range(10)`
2. `False in range(10)`
3. `0 in range(10)`
4. `True`

The reason for `3 -> 4` is that `0` resides inside the `range(0,10)` and the expression `0 in range(10)` is evaluated to a Boolean result (i.e. `True` or `False`) depends on whether the left side (`0`) is indeed **in** the right side (`range(0,10)`)

Comment: Maybe add a link to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). In particular, while the concept of comparison chaining may be understood, it might not be clear that `in` also counts as a comparison.